# How to find how many same words in array and not to repeat them in perl?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "How many words in array?\n";
$x = <STDIN>;
$i = 0;

while($i < $x ){
print "Enter $i word\n";
$y = <STDIN>;
$arr[$i]= $y;
$i++;
};

$i = 0;
$hm = @arr;

for (my $i=0; $i < $hm; $i++){
my $many = grep(/$arr[$i]/, @arr);
print "$arr[$i] repeats $many times\n";
}
```

So, If I enter that I want to have 5 words in my array, "hello" and "bye" I get result like this:

> hello
>   repeats 3 times
>   hello
>   repeats 3 times
>   hello
>   repeats 3 times
>   bye
>   repeats 2 times
>   bye
>   repeats 2 times

How could I get result like this:

> hello repeats 3 times 
>   bye repeats 2 times

I mean how can I avoid same words check?

Comment: Use a hash. Use the search function on this site -- this question (or a variant of it) has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: Please use `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every perl program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: always add `use strict` `use warnings` to your script. You'll save yourself a lot of heartache. Secondly, you need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your words as they come in the STDIN, otherwise they'll include the trailing newline.

I'd go about it as follows. Use a hash (or dictionary) to store each word as it comes in as the key, and the number of times it's been seen as the value. Here entering hello three times will result in a single key, `hello` associated with the value `3`.

```
print "How many words in array?\n";

my $x = <STDIN>;
my $i = 0;

my %words;

while($i < $x ){
    print "Enter $i word\n";
    my $y = <STDIN>;
    chomp($y);
    $words{$y}++;
    $i++;
```

}

Then you can just print these out for each new word entered:

```
for my $w (keys %words){
    print "$w repeats $words{$w} times ";
}

print "\n";
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this line works? `$words{$y}++;` I mean why do you use ++ ?

Comment: Oh... Now I get it... sorry for dumb question and thanks ;D

Comment: It's the same as writing `$words{$y} += 1`, the first time it sees hello the value is `1`, the second time this gets incremented by 1 to `2`..